# How to simplify the fraction $ \frac { r } {1 + (1/(1+(1/x)))} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, fractions

The simplification is:

$$ \frac {r (1 + x)} {1 + 2x} $$

but I don't understand how one can arrive at the simplified formula from:

$$ \frac { r } {1 + (1/(1+(1/x)))} $$

I've tried multiplying inverses and multiplying the whole fraction by some other value but nothing I solves to the simplified answer. If someone could take me through the process or hint me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\cfrac r {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 x}}
$$
First concentrate on the part that appears in $\Big($parentheses$\Big)$ below:
$$
\cfrac r {1 + \left( \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac1x}\right) }
$$
In the fraction $\cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac1x},$ if you multiply the numerator by $x$ you get $x.$ The denominator is two terms:
$$
1 + \frac 1 x.
$$
Multiplying the first term by $x$ yields $x;$ multiplying the second term by $x$ yields $1$ since the $x$s cancel. Then you have
$$
\cfrac r {1 + \left( \cfrac x {x+1} \right)}.
$$
Next we will multiply the numerator and denominator by $x+1.$ In the numerator, this yields $r(x+1).$ In the denominator, there are two terms:
$$
1 + \frac x {x+1}.
$$
Multiplying the first term by $x+1$ yields $x+1.$ Multiplying the second term by $x+1$ yields a cancellation so that you just get $x.$ Then the denominator is
$$
(x+1) +x.
$$
Simplify this to $2x+1.$ Then you have
$$
\frac{r(x+1)}{2x+1}.
$$

Comment: I'm astounded by the fact you can multiply just the denominator in parentheses to get $ \cfrac r {1 + \left( \cfrac x {x+1} \right)} $ and that it represents the same value as $ \cfrac r {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 x}} $. Thank you for the help, I'm going to take some additional time to think about why and how that's even possible

Comment: @MatthewS. : What is claimed in that step is that $$ \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 x} = \frac x {x+1}. $$

Comment: Yes and I just realized that you multiplied by $ \frac {x} {x} $ to get to that, which is the same as multiplying by 1, which clears up the confusion I had about how that's even possible!

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac r {1+\dfrac1{1+\frac 1x}}=\dfrac r{1+\dfrac x{x+1}}=\dfrac r {\left(\dfrac{2x+1}{x+1}\right)}.$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I'd have a better understanding if you explained how you arrived at the second step. The rearrangement doesn't make sense to me, I don't even understand how you got to the second step in your answer here.

Comment: @MatthewS.:  You can multiply anything by $\dfrac yy=1$ without changing it; so $\dfrac 1{1+\dfrac1x}\dfrac xx=\dfrac x{x+1}$ and $1+\dfrac x{x+1}=\dfrac{x+1}{x+1}+\dfrac x{x+1}=\dfrac {(x+1)+x}{x+1}=\dfrac {2x+1}{x+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Start by building the expression from the inside out. Let's successively form and simply the expression in the following sequence:

- First: Simplify $1+(1/x)$
- Second: $1/(1+(1/x))$ by simplifying $1/(\textrm{first result})$
- Third: $1+(1/(1+(1/x)))$ by simplifying $1+\textrm{ second result}$
- Fourth: $\dfrac{r}{1+(1/(1+(1/x)))}$ by simplifying $r/(\textrm{third result})$

Here we go:
$$1 + (1/x) = 1 + \frac1x = \frac xx + \frac1x = \frac{x+1}x\tag{first}$$
Note we had to get a common denominator to do the addition of fractions above.
$$1/(1+(1/x)) = \frac{1}{1+(1/x)} = \frac{1}{\frac{x+1}x} = \frac 11\cdot \frac{x+1}x= \frac x{x+1}\tag{second}$$
Note we divided fractions above by flipping the divisor and multiplying instead. We also created a fraction by supplying the implicit denominator $1$ if is isn't present.
$$1+(1/(1+(1/x))) = 1 + \frac x{x+1} = \frac{x+1}{x+1} + \frac x{x+1} = \frac{2x+1}{x+1}\tag{third}$$
Again, we had to get a common denominator above in order to add fractions.
$$\dfrac{r}{1+(1/(1+(1/x)))}=\frac r{\frac{2x+1}{x+1}}= \frac r1\cdot\frac{x+1}{2x+1} = \frac{r(x+1)}{2x+1}\tag{fourth}$$
Again, we perform division by flipping the divisor and multiplying instead; and we supplied the implicit denominator of $1$ where needed.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\frac{r}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}&=\frac{r}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{x+1}{x}}}\\&= \frac{r}{1+\frac{x}{x+1}}\\&=\frac{r}{\frac{x+1+x}{x+1}}\\&=\frac{r}{\frac{2x+1}{x+1}}\\&=\frac{r(x+1)}{2x+1} \end{align}$$